# Stars shape moving at night

Tags: identify-this-object

A few days ago I saw more than 50 stars moving in a group at night in SW of Florida, what this could be satellites or something else?

Comment: Did you check your local news to see if there were any light shows, festivals, things like that happening nearby? We'll need more info to help rule out any causes closer to home.

Comment: Fifty ?  Not Satellites.  Moving ?  Not stars.  In short not astronomical so off-topic.

Comment: Probably you saw this : http://a398.idata.over-blog.com/2/32/10/37/080109-thailand-tour-hmed5p.h2.jpg